# for better understanding of phantom.exit()

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {
    console.log('before IF');
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        phantom.exit();
    }
    console.log('LOADED');
    phantom.exit();
});

console.log(function(){
    return 'Im in function1';
}());
console.log(function(){
    return 'Im in function2';
}());
console.log(function(){
    return 'Im in function3';
}());
```

and when I run it, I get the next output:

```
Im in function 
Im in function1 
Im in function2 
Im in function3 
before IF 
LOADED
```

Why is this happens? I call exit() function and it should shut down the script (or am I missing smth?).
This is from official phantomJS doc:

> Exits the program with the specified return value. If no return value
>   is specified, it is set to 0.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: That's the way callbacks are working. When you call page.open(...), then in background he loads the webpage and in the mean time the script is going on to execute things like your console logs. And after your open(...) finished, it will call the function handed over.

Comment: @Kyon so, I call page.open(...). phantomJS loads page and at the same time he continues to execute next functions in the script. But when page is loaded, phantomJS still execute my console logs, he didn't interrupt execution of next functions, he executes all of them and only after that he calls the function handed over (I tried to add hundreds of console logs and phantomJS first console logs and only when all console logs are executed he calls the function handed over).

Comment: @Zirochka, that's an interesting name :)... Ukraine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I call page.open(...). phantomJS **loads page** and at the same time he
>   continues to execute next functions in the script.

No, it doesn't load a page at once. It *adds the task to open a page* to [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). It then proceeds to parse and execute the script. Only after the current script is over and all functions in the current callstack are finished, JS starts working on tasks in the event loop. So it finds there the task to open a page and opens the page. By this time all your `console.log` statements have been executed.

Once the page is open, it adds the task to loop to run your callback you passed into `page.open()`.